# How to set scanfilter in Amazon-Dynamodb for iOS?

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to set scanfilter while fetching of data from Dynamodb.
DynamoDBScanRequest  *request  = [[[DynamoDBScanRequest alloc] initWithTableName:TEST_TABLE_NAME] autorelease];

can any body let me know how i can set scan filter in the above code?

Comment: looking for the same thing

Comment: Did anyone have answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792359/dynamodb-scanexpression-with-scan-filter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

[ScanFilter](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v1/blob/973a5c2075f050ce20470fcb1e82c5d6cd06a080/src/Amazon.DynamoDB/Model/DynamoDBScanRequest.m#L39) is a dictionary, where the keys are attribute names and the values indicate the conditions the items returned by the Scan call must meet. This appears to be part of the legacy-v1 DynamoDB API. You gain access to more features like [filter (condition) expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.ConditionExpressions) in [Scans](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDBModel.h#L1391), and higher level abstractions like the [ObjectMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html#getting-started), if you use the v2 [aws-sdk-ios SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSDynamoDB).