# dynamodb scanexpression with scan filter in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-ios

```
    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.exclusiveStartKey = nil;
    scanExpression.limit = @20;
    [[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[DDBTableRow class]
                      expression:scanExpression]
      continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) { ................
```

I am able to scan through and return the first 20 recorded from a specific table from my DynamoDB as shows on a piece of code above.

The question now is I want to add a `scanExpression.scanFilter =`   property but I haven't find any good direction on how to build that.  I am using `AWSiOSSDKv2` aws sdk for iOS on `xcode6`

here is what I have so far. It is not complete yet:

```
    AWSDynamoDBCondition *condition = [AWSDynamoDBCondition new];
    AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *attribute = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
    attribute.N = @"400";
    condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperatorEQ;

    NSDictionary *scanFilter = @{@"lat":
                                     @{@"AttributeValueList":attribute,
                                       @"ComparisonOperator":@1}
                                 };
    scanExpression.scanFilter = scanFilter;
```

Comment: in short what is the structure of a `scanFilter` dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as follows:

```
AWSDynamoDBCondition *condition = [AWSDynamoDBCondition new];
AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *attribute = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
attribute.N = @"400";
condition.attributeValueList = @[attribute];
condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperatorEQ;
scanExpression.scanFilter = @{@"lat": condition};
```

Comment: awesome!! the concept is out there but not specifically to Objective-c or to the V2 or the sdk

Comment: Any suggestion on what to do if I want to perform a scan using multiple parameters? `scanExpression.scanFilter = @{@"lat": condition, @"longitude":longitudeCondition};` is it correct way to do?